# Conflicting Type Signature

Tags: haskell

This bit of code reads a directory and puts all the .ini filenames in a list. It then goes through the list reading each file, parsing it, and placing the parsed result and filename in a map (Key=filename, contents=parsed result - Config). My question is how can I get this line `rslt <- parseFromFile parseIni fn` to fit in with the type signature of `getIni`? `parseFromFile` has type signature `monad m => m (Maybe Config)` which doesn't fit in. Alternatively could somebody suggest a better way of coding it? I have only included the relavent code here. The functions in question are `main` and `getIni`.

```
import System.FilePath.Glob (globDir, compile)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Control.Applicative
import Text.Trifecta

fPath = "c:/users/tyrone/myprojects/chp29"

type FileName = String
type Name = String
type Value = String
type Assignments = Map Name Value

newtype Header = Header String deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Section = Section Header Assignments deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype Config = Config (Map Header Assignments) deriving (Eq, Show)

parseIni :: Parser Config
parseIni = do
  sections <- some parseSection
  let mapOfSections = foldr rollup M.empty sections
  return $ Config mapOfSections

getIni :: FileName -> Map FileName Config -> Map FileName Config
getIni fn mp = do
  rslt <- parseFromFile parseIni fn
  case rslt of
    Nothing -> M.empty
    Just confg -> do let ky = tail $ dropWhile (/= '\\') fn
                     M.insert ky confg mp

main :: IO ()
main = do
  iniF <- (concat . fst) <$> globDir [compile "*.ini"] fPath
  print $ foldr getIni M.empty iniF
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `parseFromFile` would presumably have the type `IO (Maybe Config)` (I'm basing this off of it needing to do IO to read the file contents, and the fact that your case expression matches on Just and Nothing), so if you're going to use it in `getIni` then it also needs to return a type in `IO`, possibly something like `IO (Map FileName Config)`.  This would make `getIni` look more like

```
getIni :: FileName -> Map FileName Config -> IO (Map FileName Config)
getIni fn mp = do
    rslt <- parseFromFile parseIni fn
    case rslt of
        Nothing -> return M.empty
        Just confg -> do
            let ky = tail $ dropWhile (/= '\\') fn
            return $ M.insert ky confg mp
```

Then to use it in `main`, you would have to use a monadic fold instead of the pure `foldr`.  Also, you may want to have `Nothing -> return mp` instead, since a parse error will wipe out whatever files you've already parsed.

Alternatively, you could build a `Map FileName String` mapping the filename to the contents, then you can use pure functions like `M.map` and `M.filter` to turn this into a `Map FileName Config`.  There's functions in `Data.Map` that would even allow you to do

```
parseIniFiles :: Map FileName String -> (Map FileName ParseError, Map FileName Config)
parseIniFiles contentMap = M.mapEither (parse parseIni "ini") contentMap
```

And your `main` would look like

```
main = do
    iniF <- (concat . fst) <$> globDir [compile "*.ini"] fPath
    contentMap <- M.fromList <$> do
        contents <- mapM readFile iniF
        -- As an aside, there is a better way to get the stem of the file path
        -- Go look for a function that will split file paths into their components
        return (tail $ dropWhile (/= '\\') fn, contents)
    let (invalidFiles, validFiles) = parseIniFiles contentMap
    putStrLn "Valid files"
    print validFiles
    putStrLn "Invalid Files"
    print invalidFiles
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't compiled any of this code, but it should give you the general idea)

Comment: Thanks for that. I replaced foldr with foldM, changed the parameters and type signatures around a bit and all good. Haven't looked at your alternative solution but will do so asap.